# .tsv Output file not importing correctly in Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, import, hive, hiveql

I am trying to import hive query result in `.tsv` format, but it's not importing results properly. I use putty terminal to interact. When I execute the query in hive environment it gives me the proper result, but when I try to execute the query in Hadoop environment using following command it won't capture the proper result.

```
hive -e"select substr(trim(split(column1,'\\|')[1]),1,1), column1, column2, from Table_X" > /home/test1.tsv
```

Maybe it is because of regular expression `('|')` ???

Comment: It's almost definitely related to the shell interpretation of your hive command. Have you tried removing the \ escape character and running the command?

Comment: @economy, I have tried removing \ escape charter but it didn't work.

Comment: "it won't capture the proper result."  What is the ***exact*** error you are getting?  I'm guessing it is because you are trying to put it in `/home` and you probably don't have proper permissions.

Comment: Hi @GoBrewers14 the exact error is when try to extract sub-string using  "substr(trim(split(column1,'\\|')[1]),1,1)" function it wont extract the exact string in tsv or csv format. for e.g. consider this sample string. "POS1 | 5P0011 | 36EB0395-4A75-49AB-BD9A-71DA1E2C114D |" I want to extract "5" from string "5P0011" which occurs after '|' , but instead extracting '5' it was extracting 'O' from the string "POS1" when i import the result in tsv or csv which is wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem.  I am running your query and it is returning "P" into a `.tsv` file.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 do u tried running this query in putty?

Comment: Negative, I don't use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

replace double backslash`\\` with triple backslash`\\\` while executing from command prompt

```
hive -e "select substr(trim(split('POS1 | 5P0011 | 36EB0395-4A75-49AB-BD9A-71DA1E2C114D |','\\\|')[1]),1,1)"
```